# How to configure Ambassador to be able to map to multiple ports on a container

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress, ambassador

I am using Ambassador as the ingress controller for my kubernetes setup. I need to connect to multiple ports on my containers, for example, I have a RethinkDB container and I need to connect to port 8085 for its web-ui, port 28015 for RDB-API and port 29015 for adding nodes to Rethinkdb and clustering.

I tried different configuration but they didn't work. The configurations that I tried:
1- This configuration works for the latest mapping which means if I replace 8085 mapping with 29015 and put it at the end I am able to access the web-ui but not other parts and so on.

```
getambassador.io/config: |
  ---
  apiVersion: ambassador/v1
  kind: Mapping
  name: rethinkdb_mapping
  prefix: /rethinkdb:28015/
  service: rethinkdb:28015
  labels:
    ambassador:
      - request_label:
        - rethinkdb:28015
  ---
  apiVersion: ambassador/v1
  kind: Mapping
  name: rethinkdb_mapping
  - prefix: /rethinkdb:8085/
    service: rethinkdb:8085
  labels:
    ambassador:
      - request_label:
        - rethinkdb:8085
  ---
  apiVersion: ambassador/v1
  kind: Mapping
  name: rethinkdb_mapping
  prefix: /rethinkdb:29015/
  service: rethinkdb:29015
  labels:
    ambassador:
      - request_label:
        - rethinkdb:29015
```

2- This one didn't work at all

```
getambassador.io/config: |
  ---
  apiVersion: ambassador/v1
  kind: Mapping
  name: rethinkdb_mapping
  - prefix: /rethinkdb:8085/
    service: rethinkdb:8085
 - prefix: /rethinkdb:29015/
   service: rethinkdb:29015
 - prefix: /rethinkdb:28015/
   service: rethinkdb:28015
```

How shall I configure Ambassador so I can have access to all ports of my container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put different names of Mappings like in example below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rethinkdb
  annotations:
    getambassador.io/config: |
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: rethinkdb_mapping
      prefix: /rethinkdb:28015/
      service: rethinkdb:28015
      labels:
        ambassador:
          - request_label:
            - rethinkdb:28015
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: rethinkdb_mapping1
      prefix: /rethinkdb:8085/
      service: rethinkdb:8085
      labels:
        ambassador:
          - request_label:
            - rethinkdb:8085
      ---
      apiVersion: ambassador/v1
      kind: Mapping
      name: rethinkdb_mapping2
      prefix: /rethinkdb:29015/
      service: rethinkdb:29015
      labels:
        ambassador:
          - request_label:
            - rethinkdb:29015
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
```

Remember to put right name of service into service label inside mappings definition.

**Note on indents and   correct syntax.**

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is almost identical to my own config except the "spec" part at the end. Can you please describe more how shall I change the mapping names? BTW the problem with indents and syntax was because I was testing different configs to see if one of them works or not and I just copied the last one but I test it again with correct indents but as I said just the last one works. Another thing is that is the name of my service for RDB and it was working for other ingress controllers such as Traefik.

Comment: I updated my answer simple it is about to change mapping names, it's up to you how to name it most important to be different like: mapping1, mapping2, mapping3. But every prefixes should include names as service. If problem still exist - speaking about connection between names ofservice for RDB which is working for other ingress controllers, just create separate  service which will be designed to ingress controller.

Comment: If I have timeout value that is common for all the mappings, is there a way to add it as common value instead of adding it to each mapping?